# How do I add filters to GROUPING_ID results?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following query...

```
SELECT a.countryRegion, a.Stateprovince, SUM (soh.TotalDue) AS revenue,
CASE
WHEN GROUPING_ID(a.countryregion,a.stateprovince) = 0 THEN 'State/Province'
WHEN GROUPING_ID(a.countryregion,a.stateprovince) = 3 THEN 'Total'
WHEN GROUPING_ID(a.countryregion,a.stateprovince) = 1 THEN  'Country Total'
ELSE N'unknown'
END AS 'Level'
FROM saleslt.address AS a
JOIN saleslt.customeraddress AS ca
ON a.addressID = ca.addressID
JOIN saleslt.customer AS c
ON ca.customerID = c.customerID
JOIN salesLT.salesorderheader as soh 
ON c.customerID = soh.customerID
GROUP BY ROLLUP(a.countryregion, a.stateprovince)
ORDER BY  a.countryregion,a.stateprovince;
```

How do I get the row for Country to contain the value ‘United States Subtotal’, and the row for state/province to contain the value ‘California Subtotal’ for example?

The table includes about 8 distinct states/provinces and multiple countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your, `GROUP BY ROLLUP(a.countryregion, a.stateprovince)`  statement should return fields with NULL values before the sub-totals.

You can substitute these NULL values with "Sub Total:" by changing your select statement as follow:

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(a.countryRegion,"Sub Total:") as countryRegion,
    coalesce(a.Stateprovince, "Sub Total:") as Stateprovince, .............
```

You can format your report output to get rid of repeated subtotals, or use a subquery to clean up repetition.

You can look at the LEAD() and LAG() Windowing Functions, to get the `countryRegion` and `StateProvince` from the previous line.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan! I was starting to lose hope as I hadn't got a answer all night. It seemed like a complex question but all it needed was that coalesce and the pieces fell right into place.